# Reshape the dataframe using unique ID and transpose the row to column based on the corresponding value

Tags: r, data-structures, transpose, data-cleaning

I have a dataframe like the following

| Sample ID | Parameter | Value | Unit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | apple | 30 | g |
| 1 | pear | 15 | lb |
| 1 | organge | 20 | kg |
| 2 | apple | 2 | g |
| 2 | pear | 3 | lb |
| 2 | orange | 10 | kg |
| 3 | apple | 15 | g |
| 3 | pear | 23 | lb |
| 3 | orange | 12 | kg |

I would like to transpose it based on the sample ID and put the corresponding value in the column

| Sample ID | apple_value_unit(g) | pear_value_unit(lb) | orange_value_unit(kg) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 30 | 15 | 20 |
| 2 | 2 | 3 | 10 |
| 3 | 15 | 23 | 12 |

Is there any ways that I can transpose and match the value? I tried the cast(), but it does not work on mapping the value to the corresponding parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can concatenate the 'Parameter' and 'Unit' columns to a single column before doing the reshape to 'wide' format with `pivot_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
   mutate(Parameter = sprintf('%s_value_unit(%s)', Parameter, Unit),
        .keep = "unused") %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = Parameter, values_from = Value)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 4
  SampleID `apple_value_unit(g)` `pear_value_unit(lb)` `orange_value_unit(kg)`
     <int>                 <int>                 <int>                   <int>
1        1                    30                    15                      20
2        2                     2                     3                      10
3        3                    15                    23                      12
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(SampleID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L
), Parameter = c("apple", "pear", "orange", "apple", "pear", 
"orange", "apple", "pear", "orange"), Value = c(30L, 15L, 20L, 
2L, 3L, 10L, 15L, 23L, 12L), Unit = c("g", "lb", "kg", "g", "lb", 
"kg", "g", "lb", "kg")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! When I run through using my large data set, now it does transpose and show the value+unit, but it does not show the unique sample ID. Is that because i have other columns in my dataset too? Now it shows like | Sample ID| apple_value_unit(g)| pear_value_unit(lb)|orange_value_unit(kg)|
| -------- | -------------- | -------- | -------|
| 1        | 30    |    |  |
| 1       |     | 15   |10  |
| 1       |  |   |20  |

Comment: @alexissunsmile It could be because the combinations will be different when other columns are present.  You may need to remove the other columns

Comment: Many thanks! Is there any ways to combine all rows with the same ID together then? Now it seems that I have multiple rows for a single ID. I guess I just need to combine all the rows with same single ID together then. One step away. Any function to recommend?

Comment: @alexissunsmile instead of that, you may select onnly the columns of interest i.e. `df1 %>% select(SampleID, Parameter, Value, Unit)%>%mutate(Parameter = sprintf('%s_value_unit(%s)', Parameter, Unit),
        .keep = "unused") %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = Parameter, values_from = Value)`

Comment: Just one more question, after I got the pivot table, I try to export it by using write.csv, but then I found that it gives me an error message 'Error in utils::write.table(w, "pivot.csv", col.names = NA, sep = ",",  : 
  unimplemented type 'list' in 'EncodeElement''

Comment: @alexissunsmile ok bye

Comment: Sorry for the vague description. But the pivot really works. Thank you so much! I try to cast vote for your answer, but I guess because my reputation is less than 15, so I cannot upvoke

Comment: Got it! Thanks!

Comment: why not use `write.csv` i.e. `write.csv(out, "pivot.csv",  quote = FALSE)`

Comment: It still gives me an error for "unimplemented type 'list' in 'EncodeElement'.   It may because when I pivot the table, there are values that null. For some Sample ID, it does not contain all the parameters. So there are a lot of null values after pivot. When I try to export it, the file I got is just one line with all the row names, and there is no data in it.

Comment: @alexissunsmile that means you have duplicate elements.  Try `out <- df1 %>% 
   mutate(Parameter = sprintf('%s_value_unit(%s)', Parameter, Unit),
        .keep = "unused") %>% mutate(rn = data.table::rowid(Parameter)) %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = Parameter, values_from = Value) %>% select(-rn)`